# RegisterPostBackControls in UpdatePanel after partial postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik

Currently I am working on migration of our web applcation from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.6.1. In this migration we were facing problem of Response.Redirect not working in case control is in UpdatePanel. But then we found solution to register postback using command.

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnViewHistory);
```

This statement allows to redirect the page but then another problem arises.

Support we have repeater control in UpdatePanel with 2 buttons 1. Edit, 2. ShowMessage.
If user comes to page and clicks on "Edit" button then user is redirected to Edit page. it works fine til now. But if user clicks on "ShowMessage" button which shows jQuery pop with some message and stays on same page. After pop up is closed, Edit button stops working and no redirect happens when clicking on it. In devTool it shows below error.

```
ScriptResource.axd?d=JnUc-DEDOM5KzzVKtsL1tThQiyHdLKhpowp3haErZKv6k2DZphOCMxhYOmqVubfNB4ASzRZ-WmXlbG…:885 Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

Could somebody tell me how to do RegisterPostBackControls in UpdatePanel after partial postback?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [IsInAsyncPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack == true)
        {
            //do stuff on partial postback
        }

        //if you want buttons in an updatepanel Repeater to trigger a full postback you need to register them for it
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            Button btn = item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is OK for controls outside repeater but how to do it for repeater controls? Do I need to iterate all the controls in repeater and register?

Comment: If the button in the update panel needs to do a full postback then yes. Added it to my example.

Comment: If this is the solution then I think it will be very tedious job for me as I have 300+ pages in my application. Do you have any other solution? or you know why it does not work in latest framework but .net 3.5?

Comment: Maybe there is something else going on. You are also talking about a modal popup. Is the problem not in there?